# Android Compose PagerState scroll state

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am implementing the Grid calendar in HorizontalPager and the schedule HorizontalPager below it.
However, there is a problem.
You need to scroll through the schedule horizontalPager based on the date selected in Calendar, but you also need to change the selected date when you swipe the schedule horizontalPager.
There is a problem with this code.

```
@Composable
fun HorizontalCalendar(
    pagerState: PagerState,
    headerMonth: LocalDate,

    changeMonth: (LocalDate) -> Unit,
) {
    var selectedDate by remember { mutableStateOf(headerMonth) } 

    LaunchedEffect(pagerState.currentPage) {
        val pagedMonth = LocalDate.of(
            yearRange.first + pagerState.currentPage / 12,
            pagerState.currentPage % 12 + 1,
            1
        )
        changeMonth(pagedMonth)

        selectedDate = if (YearMonth.from(pagedMonth) != currentYearMonth){
            pagedMonth.withDayOfMonth(1)
        } else {
            pagedMonth.withDayOfMonth(currentDate.dayOfMonth)
        }
    }

    HorizontalPager(
        state = pagerState,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top
    ) { page ->

        val year = yearRange.first + page / 12
        val month = page % 12 + 1
        val calendarDate = LocalDate.of(year, month, 1)

        CalendarGrid(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 10.dp),
            calendarDate = calendarDate,
            selectedDate = if (page == pagerState.currentPage) selectedDate else null,
            onSelectDate = { selectedDate = it }
        ).also {
            DlogUtil.d(MyTag, "Recomposition HorizontalCalendar CalendarGrid")
        }
    }.also {
        DlogUtil.d(MyTag, "Recomposition HorizontalCalendar HorizontalPager")
    }



    HorizontalScheduler(
        monthDate = headerMonth,
        selectedDate = selectedDate,
        onSelectDate = { selectedDate = it }
    ).also {
        DlogUtil.d(MyTag, "Recomposition HorizontalCalendar HorizontalScheduler")
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun HorizontalScheduler(
    monthDate: LocalDate,
    selectedDate: LocalDate,
    onSelectDate: (LocalDate) -> Unit,
){
    val month by rememberUpdatedState(monthDate)

    val lastDay = month.lengthOfMonth() + 1
    val prevMonth = month.minusMonths(1)
    val nextMonth = month.plusMonths(1)

    val days = (0..lastDay).toMutableList().map{
        when (it) {
            0 -> prevMonth
            lastDay -> nextMonth
            else -> month.withDayOfMonth(it)
        }
    }

    var currentPage by remember { mutableIntStateOf(selectedDate.dayOfMonth) }

    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(currentPage) { days.size }

    LaunchedEffect(pagerState.currentPage){
        snapshotFlow { pagerState.currentPage }.collect{
            when(it){
                in 1..month.lengthOfMonth() -> {
                    currentPage = it
                    val selected = days[it]
                    onSelectDate(selected)
                }
                else -> {

                }
            }
        }
    }

    HorizontalPager(
        state = pagerState
    ){ page ->
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ){
            Text(text = "${days[page]}")
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(selectedDate){
        pagerState.animateScrollToPage(selectedDate.dayOfMonth)
    }

}
```

Swipe the SchedulerPager through HorizontalScheduler's "LaunchedEffect (pagerState.currentPage)" to move the selected dates in the calendar above well.
But it works weird when you click Day in Grid Calendar.

The selectedDate is changed through onSelectDate(selected) in LaunchedEffect(pagerState.currentPage), which causes an error when running, such as LaunchedEffect(selectDate).

I can't think of any other way than to call onSelectDate(selected) in Launched Effect(pagerState.currentPage).

[Problem PagerState](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z800z.gif)

Is there a better way to change selectedDate when HorizontalSchedulerPagerState is swiped?

Comment: Check your descriptive text whether you named everything correctly, and mark variables, classes etc via backticks. Otherwise people will get confused.